# C# Code that Parses the Response from Restful Webservice

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, parsing, restful-url

I have a webservice that reads the response. It can't parse the response data, because the `emsg` is null.

Below is the restful webservice, connected to it, and the data returned.

```
if (response.Body != null && response.Body != "null")
{
    var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(response.Body);
    var emsg = xDocument.Element("T_OUTPUT").LastNode;

        if (emsg != null)
        {
            var parsedData =
            (
                from e in xDocument.Element("items").Descendants()
                select new ProductPipelineTankInventoryEntity
                {
                    BUKRS = (long)e.Element("BUKRS"),
                    WERKS = (long)e.Element("WERKS"),
                    NAME1 = e.Element("NAME1").ToString(),
                    REGIO = e.Element("REGIO").ToString(),
                    MATKL = e.Element("MATKL").ToString(),
                    MATNR = (long)e.Element("MATNR"),
                    LGORT = e.Element("LGORT").ToString(),
                    GRDIP = (double)e.Element("GRDIP"),
                    TRNDATE = DateTime.Parse(e.Element("TRNDATE").ToString()),
                    VOL_NATURAL = (double)e.Element("VOL_NATURAL"),
                    GRDIP_RUN = (double)e.Element("GRDIP_RUN"),
                    VOL_RUNNING = (double)e.Element("VOL_RUNNING")
                }
            ).ToList();

            ret.AddRange(parsedData);
        }
    }


    <ns0:YV_PIPELINE_PLANT_DIP_DETAILS.Response xmlns:ns0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
        <E_MSG/>
        <T_OUTPUT>
            <item>
                <BUKRS>2200</BUKRS>
                <WERKS>2222</WERKS>
                <NAME1>IOCL,JHARSUGUDA TERMINAL</NAME1>
                <REGIO>OR</REGIO>
                <MATKL>BULK-MS</MATKL>
                <MATNR>16400</MATNR>
                <LGORT>T005</LGORT>
                <GRDIP>1005.5</GRDIP>
                <TRNDATE>2019-08-05</TRNDATE>
                <VOL_NATURAL>2048.080</VOL_NATURAL>
                <GRDIP_RUN>0825.5</GRDIP_RUN>
                <VOL_RUNNING>1686.155</VOL_RUNNING>
            </item>
            <item>
                <BUKRS>2200</BUKRS>
                <WERKS>2222</WERKS>
                <NAME1>IOCL,JHARSUGUDA TERMINAL</NAME1>
                <REGIO>OR</REGIO>
                <MATKL>BULK-MS</MATKL>
                <MATNR>16400</MATNR>
                <LGORT>T006</LGORT>
                <GRDIP>173.9</GRDIP>
                <TRNDATE>2019-08-05</TRNDATE>
                <VOL_NATURAL>776.741</VOL_NATURAL>
                <GRDIP_RUN>0915.9</GRDIP_RUN>
                <VOL_RUNNING>4130.508</VOL_RUNNING>
            </item>
        </T_OUTPUT>
    </ns0:YV_PIPELINE_PLANT_DIP_DETAILS.Response>
```

The above code I tried. Below part is of the response output.

Comment: Where does response.Body come from?  Show the related code and be clear about the classes involved.

Comment: "i am unable to parse the response" : always post full error messages, unexpected results etc.

Comment: `xDocument.Element("items")` does not exist in the sample you have provided, so that will be an issue, once you get to that point.

Comment: Edited your question heavily, I realize your English wasn't good. I hope that is what you meant. It should help you get an answer promptly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have namespaces and change from "items" to "item".  For test I read xml from a file instead of a response.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlResponse = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponse);
            XElement emsg = xDocument.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "T_OUTPUT").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = emsg.GetDefaultNamespace();

            if (emsg != null)
            {
                var parsedData =
                (
                    from e in xDocument.Descendants(ns + "item")
                    select new ProductPipelineTankInventoryEntity
                    {
                        BUKRS = (long)e.Element(ns + "BUKRS"),
                        WERKS = (long)e.Element(ns + "WERKS"),
                        NAME1 = (string)e.Element(ns + "NAME1"),
                        REGIO = (string)e.Element(ns + "REGIO"),
                        MATKL = (string)e.Element(ns + "MATKL"),
                        MATNR = (long)e.Element(ns + "MATNR"),
                        LGORT = (string)e.Element(ns + "LGORT"),
                        GRDIP = (double)e.Element(ns + "GRDIP"),
                        TRNDATE = (DateTime)e.Element(ns + "TRNDATE"),
                        VOL_NATURAL = (double)e.Element(ns + "VOL_NATURAL"),
                        GRDIP_RUN = (double)e.Element(ns + "GRDIP_RUN"),
                        VOL_RUNNING = (double)e.Element(ns + "VOL_RUNNING")
                    }
                ).ToList();

            }
        }
    }
    public class ProductPipelineTankInventoryEntity
    {
        public long BUKRS { get; set; }
        public long WERKS { get; set; }
        public string NAME1 { get; set; }
        public string REGIO { get; set; }
        public string MATKL { get; set; }
        public long MATNR { get; set; }
        public string LGORT { get; set; }
        public double GRDIP { get; set; }
        public DateTime TRNDATE { get; set; }
        public double VOL_NATURAL { get; set; }
        public double GRDIP_RUN { get; set; }
        public double VOL_RUNNING { get; set; }

    }


}
```